# Player not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im having some issues with player not defined errors this is the error and the codes i have putten links to the pictures of it.Im pretty new at python and i don't understand most of the errors,i will be happy if someone could help.

[Player not defined errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsn0a.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsUSf.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKjQ0.png)

Comment: Please don't just provide links to code. Why have you not included it in your question as formatted text?

Comment: It was just putted in one line

Comment: We don't care about things being on one line. It's far more important that you include the code as text so people can copy/paste the code if they need to test something, rather than type the whole thing out. That's helping us to help you. Your question should be self-contained

Comment: @Vilhemiuu Welcome to SO! Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand what constitues a good question.

Comment: You should post code as text, not as images. Anyway your error is due to a typo. You define the class as `player` and call it as `Player`... Mind the `p/P`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a minimal working code about your attached pictures. Mostly your global variable handling was not correct. You can find my comments in the below code as comments.

**Code:**

```
# Define global variable
current_player = None


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.other = 100


def main():
    option = input("Option: ")
    if option == "1":
        start()


def start():
    # Use the global variable inside the function.
    global current_player
    user_name = input("Name: ")
    # Assign the Player instance to the global variable.
    current_player = Player(name=user_name)
    start1()


def start1():
    # Use the global variable inside the function.
    global current_player
    # Get the "name" attribute of the "Player" object.
    print("Hello my friend: {}".format(current_player.name))


main()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Option: 1
Name: Bill
Hello my friend: Bill

>>> python3 test.py 
Option: 1
Name: Jill
Hello my friend: Jill
```

**Note:**

I suggest to get rid of the global variable usage. Pass the required variables as parameters. I have implemented a version which doesn't contain global variables.

```
def start():
    user_name = input("Name: ")
    # Assign the Player instance to the global variable.
    current_player = Player(name=user_name)
    start1(current_player)


def start1(current_player_info):
    # Get the "name" attribute of the "Player" object.
    print("Hello my friend: {}".format(current_player_info.name))
```

Comment: Thanks  I was using this code from this guy https://youtu.be/yVm6olQ2sj8